# How to stop all running threads in ThreadPoolTaskExecutor?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I am add new threads like this using `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` :

```
threadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            doSomething();
        }

        Thread.sleep(1000); 
    }

});
```

All active threads are not stopped, when I shutdown this executor:

`threadPoolTaskExecutor.shutdown();`

Is there option how to stop this active threads using `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`?

Comment: Look into thread interruption.

Comment: Thread.stop() it! Take these threads and shoot then so they'll learn who's their master.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set [setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(false)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ExecutorConfigurationSupport.html#setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown-boolean-) when create `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.

Default is `false`, shutting down immediately through interrupting ongoing tasks and clearing the queue.

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting an exception which says that `java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted`

Comment: Every thread has a boolean flag that represents its interrupted status. Initially, this status is set to false for every thread. If a thread is interrupted during an interruptible method such as join or sleep, it will unblock and throw an InterruptedException. You should handle it as well.

Comment: @GreenLeie this is a good article about dealing with InteruptedException http://www.javaspecialists.co.za/archive/Issue056.html

Comment: Thanks, this article help a lot in understanding.

Comment: Good, I am happy because it can help.